# PHP MySQL auto-create hardcoded hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql

Below is a picture of my database. 
I am going to make the numbers on the left (81305, 81306, etc..) all hyperlinks.

When the user clicks on the hyperlink, they will be directed to a page (all links will be this page) "dpupage.php". This page will have a form with empty values. I will then use SQL queries (according to the NUM) to fill the form with the rest of the columns according to the number they picked.

The problem I have is that I will need to email users a specific link to their specific form.

But I can't set the url to, for example: http://mysite.com/dpupage.php because it will send them to a form with empty values. How can I create a link that will open up the dpupage.php and still query the data they need.

For example: Lets say I need a user to address NUM: 81309. An email is sent to them through phpmailer with a link. This link needs to take them directly to that dpupage.php and fill in all data that corresponds with NUM 81309.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

[image: Table]

Comment: Like `http://mysite.com/dpupage.php?num=81309`?

Comment: Is that the proper syntax? I guess I would substr those numbers from the link and then use that number to query the database?

Comment: You get it with `$_GET['num']`. This is PHP web basics.

Comment: The part behind the ? is called query string. PHP offers simplified access by using `$_GET['num']`. Stuff like is something you have to know if you even think about developing for the web.

Comment: Thanks guys. As you can tell I am noob and self-learner.

Comment: @bagofmilk: Then I strongly recommend to google for HTTP methods (GET and POST in particular) and [PHP predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP

Give them a link with a parameter, for example http://mysite.com/dpupage.php?num=12345

You can get the number they used via $_GET['num']. Get your values from your DB (example: "SELECT * FROM `wahtever_your_table_is_called` WHER `NUM` = $_GET['num']).

Paste the values into the field.

Beware: that's an easy example, don't do it that way! SQL-Injections will eat your dog! Google it!

Comment: Also, you will likely need to consider some additional security, as there is nothing to prevent a user from simply changing the value in the URL and modifying another record. At a minimum you might consider using a hash instead of the integer value to make the values harder to guess.